# Switching frequency of a DC-DC

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply

I am using one of this little boy in my design:

https://www.tracopower.com/fr/fra/series/tba-1

TBA 1-0511 to be more precise.
I am observing some noise on my board so I was wondering if it could be him (SMPS and EMC, long love story...).

When looking in datasheet at which frequency he was working a range is indicated, followed by (PWM):

[image]

For the little I know in SMPS I thought the switching frequency was fixed?
What is it then?

Comment: Probably fixed on-time or fixed off-time so it varies with load and input voltage. Ask the manufacturer?

Comment: As an aside once I was involved in debugging a design someone else had done using one of these and it didn't handle current transients well and that caused noise. Does your application have fairly big fluctuations in the current requirement?

Comment: They are not necessarily fixed, no. And from my personal experience, Traco products are by means guaranteed to live up to any form of expected quality metrics, including their own spec.

Answer (score 1):

Not all switching power supplies have fixed frequency, but most of that type of isolated unregulated DC-DC converter do have fixed frequency, towards the higher end of the stated range. It's possible the supplier has some reason for giving that range even if the frequency is actually fixed.

I suggest you simply measure a sample. It should be pretty easy to see the switching frequency (for example, you could try looking at the input ripple current at various input voltages and output loads.

In general you may need a capacitor between input and output or output and ground to minimize noise (which can cause other problems, of course).

Answer (score 0):

One usual way to derive an on-off waveform is by applying the feedback signal to a relaxation oscillator. This will lead to a toggle frequency that reduces when the oscillator approaches extreme duty cycles.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fYV9hz.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Another reason for the large range given is component tolerances of the R and (in particular) C making up the relexation oscillator.

Comment: The single chip thing should already be doing this internally, that's why people pay a steep price for them. I mean, it costs around 3.5€ in volumes (not counting manual soldering cost), I'd expect a premium product for that price. If you have to fork up another >1€ to get the thing working as it should, then it's a useless product.

Comment: @Lundin not sure what you are getting at. I am trying to offer an explanation as to why some DC-DC-converters spec a rather wide oscillator frequency range, while others spec a fixed frequency value instead.